# function returns two numbers, saving that to variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

This seems like a pretty straightforward problem, but I could not find anyone who spoke about it. In the following code

```
function add(x,y) {
  return (x+7, y+4);

}
let rew= add(1,1);

console.log(rew);
```

it says rew equals five. I know we need to hold two values and rew is not an array, but I tried pushing the results into an array and that also did not work. Is there a way I can save both of these numbers into a variable to be able to manipulate them such as to then add them together?

Comment: hint: `return 3,2,1` - returns 1 ... because of the `comma operator` - also, `return (3,2,1)` is the same as `return 3,2,1`

Comment: thanks that was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the 2 values in an array then get the array elements for whatever you want to use the 2 numbers for:

```
function add(x,y) {
   return [x+7, y+4];

}
let rew= add(1,1);

console.log(rew);
```

The code prints Array [ 8, 5 ] on the console

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have syntax like that (it looks like you are trying to do C# 7's tuples). You'll get the result of `5` because of the comma operator. Use square brackets for an array result.

```js
function add(x,y) {
  return [x+7, y+4];

}
let rew= add(1,1);

console.log(rew);
```

Comment: Are you getting Service Unavailable when you try to run the snippet?

Comment: @Barmar ive seen 502's from nginx on some ads, there might be a problem somewhere...

Comment: @Barmar I have seen that on all snippets for the last 15 minutes :( Something wrong with the server used to run the snippets but this solution works so +1. Good answer.

Comment: @Barmar I was seeing that, but it just started working again for me.

Answer (score 0):

To return more than one value, you have to use a collection (array or object), but you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign it directly to 2 or more variables:

```js
function add(x,y) {
  return [x+7, y+4];
}

const [a, b] = add(1,1);

console.log('a: ', a);
console.log('b: ', b);
```